# Realizar o merge entre views de dois ou mais módulos

Tags: php, modularização, phalcon-php

Eu tenho uma aplicação Phalcon PHP modular. Estou fazendo uma interface administrativa para controlar os módulos que deverão ser utilizados no sistema.
Um dos módulos faz o controle da interface padrão da aplicação, enquanto os demais fazem a adição de determinadas funcionalidades.

Eu tenho o seguinte problema: quando um outro módulo for habilitado, ele deverá adicionar conteúdo HTML para o outro módulo de controle de interface. Desta forma gostaria de mesclar duas ou mais views. Estou utilizando o Volt como motor de construção de views.

Isso é possível de se fazer em Phalcon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erick boa tarde,

Você deve utilizar partials para fazer isso...

```
<div id="footer">{{ partial("partials/footer") }}</div>
```

Veja mais em: [Volt: Template Engine](https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.3/reference/volt.html#partial-vs-include)